# Control the base with the trajectory of MoveIt?

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-kinetic, mobile-base, mobile

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am working with Iiwa(7 DoF) + Omnirob(Omnidirectional platform). My task is making them fullfill mobile manipulation tasks, this means making the platform and arm move synchronously for a certain task.

In order to plan the trajectory I am using moveit. For the planning of the platform trajectory we have two options:

1. Creating a  P,P,R joints to define the movement of the platform. Each prismatic joint would refer to X and Y and the revolute would be the theta movement.
2. Define a virtual  planar joint from base to /odom_combined.

In my case I used the {P,P,R} joints to plan the trajectory. So basically I am planning for 3(base) + 7(arm) joints group in Moveit.

Once the plan is done I would have a trajectory in {X,Y;Theta; T} for the base, and a similar one for the arm with each Joint.

**My problem comes now.**

As far as I know, there is no any controller for the base of the robot that allows you to provide a trajectory(vector of positions with time stamp), but only we can provide a path, as move_base does.

I wonder if anybody knows any controller for omnidirectional platforms in order to provide a trajectory created in moveit {X,Y,Theta,T}. In case not, whats the usual approach for omnidirectional mobile manipulators for synchronous base-arm manipulation?

Thanks alot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284792/control-the-base-with-the-trajectory-of-moveit?/) by [TheCamusean](https://answers.ros.org/users/29734/thecamusean/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2018-03-08

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joaocabogon](https://answers.ros.org/users/36490/joaocabogon/) on 2018-07-17**:
Can you please share your URDF? How do you relate the base with the 3 PPR joints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi again,

I found an easy solution in the base of ROS.

Basically, I considered my base joints(PPR) as aregular joint and then use this information to send it to my specific robot through a custom Hardware Interface.

http://wiki.ros.org/hardware_interface

In my personal case, I based my HW interface in David Coleman's ros_control boilerplate. Here Github link:

https://github.com/davetcoleman/ros_control_boilerplate

I hope this could be useful for those people willing to do mobile manipulation.

Bye!

---

Originally posted by [TheCamusean](https://answers.ros.org/users/29734/thecamusean/) with karma: 51 on 2018-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0